# How to read file in line and back to specific line to read it again

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7, file

I am trying to find a specific string in a file(let's say this is condition 1.1) and if that string was found, I need to find another string right after condition 1.1 string (let's say this is condition 1.2). if condition 1.2 exist, I need to get back to condition 1.1 plus one line. and readline again from there in case I found string of condition 2.1 , 3.1, 4.1.

Let's say the file is something like this

```
line 1
line 2
condition 1.1
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
condition 2.1
line 9
line 10
line 11
condition 2.2
line 12
line 13
condition 1.2
```

what I've done so far are reading the file line using `f.readline` with condition 1.1 and 1.2 check without thinking about checking condition 2.1 and 2.2.

How to acheive this such scenario? I've thought about something like DFS but I dont think python file open has `readline before` functionalities

Here is my pseudocode

```
def beta(f, line):
    if("STRING A Condition 1.1" in line):
        while True:
            if("STRING B Condition 1.2" in line):
                return 1
            if(line is none):
                return None
            line = f.readline() # This is my code problem. it continues the f.readline of the caller.

def alpha():
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        line = f.readline()
        while line:
            value = beta(f, line)
            if(value is not None):
                print("dummy yes")
            line = f.readline()
            if(line is None):
                break
```

Comment: Can you reword " if the second condition exist, I need to get back to condition 1 plus one line and readline again from there in case I found string of condition 2.1 , 3.1, 4.1."? Try to make the desired functionality as clear as possible.

Comment: Okay, edited to be 1.1 and 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=seek#io.IOBase.seek) and [`tell`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=seek#io.IOBase.tell) to save and restore your place in the file.

`f.seek(x, y)` moves the current position in file `f` to a position that is offset by `x` from `y`.

`f.tell()` returns the current position in the file `f`.

For example, consider the following code:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    saved_place = 0
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        if "condition 1.1" in line:
            # save your place in the file
            saved_place = f.tell()
            while line:
                if "condition 1.2" in line:
                    # 'rewind' the file
                    f.seek(saved_place, 0)
                    print(f.read())
                line = f.readline()
        line = f.readline()
```

When you encounter condition 1.1, you can save that place in the file using `saved_place = f.tell()`, and later, restore the current position in the file to this place using `f.seek(saved_place, 0)`. The example above simply prints the file from just after 1.1 to the end, but you can replace it with whatever logic you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is working. I wanna upvote your answer too but I can't. It would be great if you can upvote my question so I can have right amount of reputation to upvote.

By the way, I use `saved_place = f.tell() + 1` to make it working in `f.seek(saved_place, 0)`. So I don't have to use `f.seek(saved_place, 2)` who need byte read